# Blinking flash light before turning on using AVCaptureSession in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, flash, avcapturedevice

I have the Scenario to turn on/off the flash light for iPhone application, Here its working perfectly for me with the following codes, But its blink once before turn ON. Here is the code

```
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Create device input and add to current session
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create video output and add to current session      
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Start session configuration
    [session beginConfiguration];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    // Set torch to on
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    [session commitConfiguration];

    // Start the session
    [session startRunning];

// Keep the session around
    [self setAVSession:session];
```

Is it possible to handle that blink before ON. If any Idea, Share with me that will be very useful. Thank's in advance..